# <video> and <audio> elements won't center

Tags: html, css, audio, video

I have added a video and an audio file to a webpage, however they don't seem to want to center.

The HTML code is:

```
<h2>Dedicated to Quality</h2>

<video height="210" class="center" controls="controls" poster="aboutus/poster.jpg">
<source src="aboutus/ucorp.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
Your browser does not support the HTML5 video element.
</video>

<p>
For the audio of this webpage, use the audio controls below.
</p>

<audio class="center" controls="controls">
<source src="aboutus/voiceover.mp3" type:"audio/mp3"/>
Your browser does not support the HTML5 audio element.
</audio>
```

The CSS code is:

```
video.center
{
display: block; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
}

audio.center
{
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

So I have already added the `display:block;` CSS classes and have the margins set to `auto`.
According to the tutorial I am following, this *should* work.
Below I have attached what I am expecting vs. what I am getting (note: disregard the video thumbnails and sizes being different).
[Expected Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6IlQ.jpg) vs [Obtained Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jSLy.jpg).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or a stackoverflow code snippet ? So people can see it for real and test things in the console, instead of screenshots.

Comment: Note: I understand that '''type:"audio/mp3"''' is incorrect syntax. Changed it and the centering problem still exists!

Comment: So this is interesting...
I've added the code to codepen, which can be found here:
https://codepen.io/jacobc1596/pen/oNgePEE
And when this display, the elements ARE centered... but when I view the code in my browser it isn't. Struggling to figure out why!

Comment: Other generic CSS rules in the website that conflicts with the one you applied ?

Comment: Nothing conflicting!

Comment: Searching through the stylesheets of [the site in question](http://ucorp.biz/about.php) I can't see any reference to `video.center` class. Just adding it in via Chrome, Firefox and Safari it works fine. So, there can only be two reasons why css is not applied. 1. it is not there or 2. it is being overwritten / overridden. Where is the `video.center` styling meant to live? double check it is actually in there.

Comment: I'm also seeing this warning `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://ucorp.biz/about.php".` you may want to check out the [source of that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629203/stylesheet-not-parsed-because-non-css-mime-types-are-not-allowed-in-strict-mode)